# Python Game "House of Cards" help needed

Tags: python, oop, object, comparison

I am currently a python newbie and am using python to create some games. I have written a game "House of Cards", and basically I am trying to use what I learn in OOP to do it. The rules are very simple -- you need the largest card to win. Players would compare the numbers first, then the suit of the card -- the person with the largest card wins. I have written the following code:

```
import itertools
import random

class Card (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.suit = ["Cubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
        self.value = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
        self.deck = []
        for card in itertools.product(self.value, self.suit):
            self.deck.append(card)

class Player(object):
    def __init__ (self, name, card = None):
        self.name = name
        self.carddeck = Card()
        self.card_available = self.carddeck.deck
    def draw_a_card(self):
        self.card = random.choice(self.card_available)
        print "%s has gotten a %s" %(self.name, self.card)
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.card_available.index(self.card) > self.card_available.index(other.card):
            print "%s wins!" %(self.name)
        elif self.card_available.index(self.card) < self.card_available.index(other.card):
            print "%s wins!" %(other.name)

player_1= Player("Player 1")
player_2 = Player("Player 2")
player_3 = Player("Player 3")
player_1.draw_a_card()
player_2.draw_a_card()
player_3.draw_a_card()
cards_deck = Card()
player_1.__cmp__(player_2)
```

After a lot of effort, I have successfully compared the cards between players 1 and 2, but I don't know how to include player 3 into the comparison.

Comment: The way you're implementing it, you'd have to do two separate comparisons: player_1 to player_2, as you're doing, and the winner of that comparison with player_3.

Comment: you can max, sort, or simply use several > to check who wins.

Comment: @njzk2 look at his override function ...

Comment: Odd, there's no mention of `Frank Underwood` in the source!

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Right, I saw there was a `__cmp__`, but not that it yields completely unexpected results.

Comment: side note: you are giving the users the possibility to draw the same card each. you would need a single deck for all player and remove the card once it was drawn.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah see my edited solution the second part ...

Comment: @njzk2 I think its more than a possibility since "deck" (read each card has its own deck for some weird reason) is never shuffled ... I think he is guaranteed to get all 3 players with the same card ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: not quite. the card is picked using `random.choice`, which does choose a card at random. I would however start by shuffling, then poping cards

Comment: ahh yeah you are correct ... but even popping he can get duplicates , since each player has his own card and each card has its own deck

Answer (score 3):

the cmp function is to override comparisons so you can do things like

`if player1 > player2: print "Player1 beat player2!"`

not so you can print some message inside the function ... by not returning anything you are essentially saying they are equal(I think in python not returning anything from cmp is roughly equivelent to returning 0), or even worse perhaps raising an error if you try a normal comparison...

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__ (self, name, card = None):
        self.name = name
        self.carddeck = Card()
        self.card_available = self.carddeck.deck
    def draw_a_card(self):
        self.card = random.choice(self.card_available)
        print "%s has gotten a %s" %(self.name, self.card)
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.card_available.index(self.card) > self.card_available.index(other.card):
            return 1
        elif self.card_available.index(self.card) < self.card_available.index(other.card):
            return -1
        return 0

print max([player1,player2,player3]), "Wins!" 
print min([player1,player2,player3]), "Loses!!!"
```

is the easiest way to do it ...

really you are missing several aspects of OOP design here

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,val,suite):
        self.val = val
        self.suite = suite
    def __int__(self):
        return self.val
    def __str__(self):
         card_name = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"][self.val]
         suite_name = ["Clubs","Spades","Diamonds","Hearts"][self.suite]
         return card_name + " of " + suite_name
    def __cmp__(self,other):
         return cmp(int(self),int(other))

print Card(1,3)
print Card(4,2) < Card(3,2)
```

notice that card has nothing to do with a deck ... it belongs in a deck

```
deck = [Card(i,j) for i in range(13) for j in range(4)]
random.shuffle(deck.shuffle)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joran said `.__cmp__()` is an operator overloading function so you could  just call `player1 > player2` rather than `player_1.__cmp__(player_2)` you could also store the players in a list and sort the list after every turn. you would still be able to reference players in the normal way. For example:

```
player_1= Player("Player 1")
player_2 = Player("Player 2")
player_3 = Player("Player 3")
exampleList = [player1,player2,player3]
player_1.draw_a_card()
player_2.draw_a_card()
player_3.draw_a_card()
exampleList.sort()
winner = exampleList[0]
```

For more info on list sorting: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: @Joran Actually __cmp__() should return -1,0,1. How ever since he didn't really stick to that, he could still use `sorted()` For example: `sorted(exampleList, key=lambda player: player.card_available.index(self.card))`